# File recovery from live disk

Tags: 14.04, live-usb, windows-10

Recently I haven't been able to boot into my primary drive which is an SSD, it has the windows installation on it and many important files. I've spent the last few days working on getting the data back. Below I will outline my process and my question will be at the end. Keep in mind this is with a windows 10 system and the problem first came up due to a sudden power loss.

The error my computer showed when booting up was a 0xc00000e9 boot/BCD error. I ran startup repair and did chkdsk C:\f and it said that the drive was in RAW format. This is weird... I never reformatted the drive, and I couldn't even if I wanted to since it's the primary drive. I tried doing the scanos command and it came up with 0 installations.

Next, I booted a live disk of Ubuntu and ran the testdisk application to analyze the drive and its partitions. When I did it showed 3 partitions each of them being ntfs WTF? Windows System Recovery just told me it was in a RAW format. Interesting note: Windows PE couldn't detect the drive, but ubuntu could.

Anyway next I ran photorec and recovered a bunch of files, after some digging I concluded all my data was safe, I just couldn't access it. The problem is that photorec doesn't include the various file formats I need recovered. Thus, I searched for another tool and came across R-Studio data recovery and UFS explorer standard recovery both linux versions. I was able to use these programs to explore the whole disk!!! The whole file structure was the same, none of my data was damaged and I was able to recover quite a lot! Here comes the problem, both R-Studio data recovery and UFS explorer standard recovery can only recover a max file size of 256kb with the demo version, the full version can do any file size but it costs a lot!

So my question is: Is there any program that can recover all my files from the drive? It's not even recovery per se because my files are safely in the drive, I just can't boot into windows on it, or access the files from ubuntu without either R-Studio data recovery or UFS explorer standard recovery, which only do a max 256kb file with the demo version. Also it's very odd that Windows System Recovery says the drive is RAW, but TestDisk says it is ntfs partition.

Comment: "important files"? Doubt it that they are that important ... otherwise you would not have a problem since you would have a backup. Or 2. Or 3.   Since we all know SSDs are prone to failure.... But ... try "scalpel". Important though: do NOT use that disk. Take it out of the system, created a new bootable system, connect this disk, make a "dd" dump from the disk and work on the dump, not the actual disk. If you do not: any write to the disk might destroy data you wanted recovered.

Comment: @Rinzwind I do have backups, problem is that they are about 2 months old. I think the drives are actually ok, maybe something messed up with the partition table. Who knows, but I'll try using scalpel.

Comment: Also the data hasn't been deleted, it looks like it's safe in the dunce l drive. I just need a way to access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get another drive >= your SSD in capacity.

Then run `sudo dd if="/dev/sdx" of="/dev/sdy"` Where x is your SSD's mount point and y is you secondary drive's mount point.

(That could take a loooong time BTW)

Then, once all your data is cloned to the other drive, you can mess around with it, and not worry about corrupting it trying to get your data back. If you corrupt it, just re-dd from your SSD.

Comment: Wow that's awesome, I'll try it

Comment: Yeah, a while back I accidentally destroyed my Windows 7 partition table, and I did this exact procedure,  ended up corrupting my external drive with the recovery tools, and re-dd-ing again before I was able to successfully recover my data.

Comment: I just tried it and it corrupts the bigger drive for some reason. I had to do chkdsk /f to the bigger drive just to fix it. Is there something I could use to just browse the SSD file system?

Comment: @user2900812 - You let the whole DD finish? *Also, of course it corrupts the bigger drive; the command clones the corrupted SSD to the bigger drive*. The idea is you play with the cloned version so that if you mess it up further, your data isn't gone :)

Comment: Can I use pv /dev/sda > /dev/sdb to do the same? I want to be able to see the progress

Comment: @user2900812 - To see the progress of DD, while it is running, open another terminal and type "sudo kill -USR1 $(pgrep ^dd)" - Then, the progress will be printed in the terminal that's running the DD.

Comment: Ok well I started it again, it's going to take quite a long time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36990/discussion-between-android-dev-and-user2900812).